# Netplan routing with two uplinks

Tags: routing, netplan

We have servers in a colocation DC and have two uplinks: A fast metered connection (for live traffic) and a slow flat rate one (for things like backups). We'd like to use a Linux box for routing and have a specific uplink be used depending on the local source subnet, effectively meaning two different default routes. This should be possible with separate routing tables, but I haven't quite been able to grok them.

The following is a faulty example netplan config, omitting things like VLANs, nameservers etc:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [ 5.5.5.2/27 ]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 5.5.5.1 # provider edge fast uplink
    eth1:
      addresses: [ 6.6.6.2/27 ]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 6.6.6.1 # provider edge cheap uplink
    eth2:
      addresses: [ 10.20.30.1/24 ]
    eth3:
      addresses: [ 10.20.40.1/24 ]
```

Outbound traffic from subnet 10.20.30.0/24 should use the fast uplink, traffic from 10.20.40.0/24 the cheap one. Also the local subnets must be able to reach each other. How should the config look to achieve that? NATing for outgoing traffic will be done via iptables.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. The configuration that solves the requirements looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [ 5.5.5.2/27 ]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 5.5.5.1 # provider edge fast uplink
    eth1:
      addresses: [ 6.6.6.2/27 ]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 6.6.6.1 # provider edge cheap uplink
          metric: 102
          table: 200
    eth2:
      addresses: [ 10.20.30.1/24 ]
      routes:
        - to: 10.20.30.0/24
          table: 200
    eth3:
      addresses: [ 10.20.40.1/24 ]
      routes:
        - to: 10.20.40.0/24
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.20.40.0/24
          table: 200
```

Notes:

- The solution uses two routing tables, the default table (which simplifies networking on the router itself) and table 200.
- As the two private subnets need to be able to reach each other despite using different routing tables, each private interface/subnet needs to add itself to the *other* routing table.

Answer (score 0):

Routing for multiple uplinks/provider:
https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/554519)

Comment: The link does not answer the question because a netplan-specific solution is required.